# Multiple middleware's in next auth

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to make multiple middleware's for diffrent pages for example one middleware would be that user needs to be logged in and thats what I have now:

/middleware.ts

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth(
  // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
  function middleware(req) {
    console.log(req.nextauth.token);
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => (token ? true : false),
    },
    secret: "blablabla",
  }
);

export const config = { matcher: ["/user"] };
```

But I need to another middleware for admin only pages for example. So I'm not sure how would I make diffrent/multiple middlewares with diffrent matchers.

I tried creating new middleware file in the specific route's directory, but it didn't load the middleware file.

Comment: You can only have one middleware file. You can check the current path you're in and apply different logic. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#conditional-statements.